# reCaptcha Not Posting Challenge or Response

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm new to reCaptcha, and am have some troubles getting it to post.

```
<form action="createUser.php" method="post">

    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword"></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcjLeoSAAAAAF5fo6FA8h6z6796Yxg4bA-Ggh7o">
            </script>
            <noscript>
                <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcjLeoSAAAAAF5fo6FA8h6z6796Yxg4bA-Ggh7o"
                        height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
                <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
                </textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                       value="manual_challenge">
            </noscript>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
    </tr>

</form>
```

On createUser.php it says that reCaptcha challenge field and response field are null, and debugging with PHP storm they aren't included in the POST at createUser.php either, and I can't seem to figure out why they wouldn't be included in the POST. Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard API if you plan to show reCAPTCHA. Check the following link.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Answer (score 0):

1.Change `action="createUser.php"` to `action="verify.php"`

and

```
<td>
            <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcjLeoSAAAAAF5fo6FA8h6z6796Yxg4bA-Ggh7o">
            </script>
            <noscript>
                <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcjLeoSAAAAAF5fo6FA8h6z6796Yxg4bA-Ggh7o"
                        height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
                <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
                </textarea>
                <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
                       value="manual_challenge">
            </noscript>
        </td>
```

TO

```
<td>
<?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "Your Public Key"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
</td>
```

2.Make a verify.php file

3.In the verify.php file add these codes-

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "Your Private Key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification

mysql_connect("localhost","Database Username","Password");
mysql_select_db("Database name");
$name=$_POST['name'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$date=$_POST['date'];
$submit=$_POST['submit'];

$dbLink = mysql_connect("localhost", "Database usename", "password");
    mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

if($comment)
{
$insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO commenttable (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment') ");  
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "Where You want to redirect User after successful signup";
</script>      
    <?php
}
else
{
echo '<div class="err">' . "Please Fill out all Fields" . '</div>';
}
}
?>
```

NOTE: Do not just copy past the codes this is just a good hint.
In The verify.php after `// Your code here to handle a successful verification`
just add the codes which will insert the user data to you database Table.